# Synchronization of groups between site collections

Tags: 2010, groups, synchronization

I have multiple site collections that all have permission groups with the same names. When a user is added to a group in one site collection that change should be synchronized with all the other site collections.

What is the most effective way to do that?

I read that there are event receivers for such events in SharePoint 2013, but my environment is SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I would create ad groups and add those ad groups in the SharePoint groups.
Because you have same group name across all site collection n permission on all site collection looks like same.

AD groups are easy no code solution, once you add AD groups in SharePoint then management operation is simple. simply add/remove the user in AD groups, SharePoint automatically add/remove the users. [TechNet Article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10550.sharepoint-2010-choosing-between-ad-groups-or-sharepoint-groups.aspx)

Other than that I think you can some kind of powershell which add user across all site collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an event receiver in SharePoint 2013 to check if an user is added to a group and make other groups in sync. This feature is not available in SharePoint 2010.

Refer below for complete set of clarifications:
http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/tag/spsecurityeventreceiver

There is class inheriting from: **GroupUserAddedFeatureEventReceiver** : SPFeatureReceiver

That should work.